# How to store a NSUInteger using NSCoding?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How do I store a `NSUInteger` using the `NSCoding` protocol, given that there is no method on `NSCoder` like `-encodeUnsignedInteger:(NSUInteger)anInt forKey:(NSString *)aKey` like there is for `NSInteger`?

The following works, but is this the best way to do this? This does needlessly create objects.

```
@interface MYObject : NSObject <NSCoding> {
    NSUInteger count;
}  

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:count] forKey:@"count"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        count = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"count"] unsignedIntegerValue];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't optimize your code for not creating objects when you first write it. It's better to get something working, than to overanalyze the code you need to write. You'll waste too much time thinking and not enough time doing.

You'll want to measure performance later, and make changes if the object creation becomes an issue. Profiling in Xcode is a great tool to learn.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that `NSUInteger` may not be the same size as an `unsigned int`. On many (if not most by now) Mac OS X machines, `NSUInteger` will be an `unsigned long`, which will be twice as big. On the other hand, a keyed archiver should handle that without a problem, since it builds a dictionary.

Further complicating matters is the fact that NSCoder doesn't have any methods to deal with unsigned types. I can't think of how this would cause any data loss, but it would require some ugly casts, plus it just feels dirty.

If you want to insist upon an unsigned type, the simplest way would be to encode the raw bytes (preferably in network byte order using `htonl` and `ntohl`) in the largest type available (`unsigned long long`) using `encodeBytes:length:forKey:` and `decodeBytesForKey:returnedLength:`. For maximum safety, you should check the length of what you decoded and cast the pointer (or use a union) to extract the correct-sized type.

The drawback of this is that the value will be represented in the output as data, not an integer. This mainly matters only if somebody decides to read in the raw plist data for your archive instead of using the keyed unarchiver like you do, and even then only to them. The other cases where it might matter is if Apple (or you) should ever switch to an architecture that has even larger integer types, types whose size in bits is not a power of two (there's at least one old platform where a word was 24 bits), or types with an unusual layout (not big- or little-endian).

As for your NSNumber solution: You might want to crack open your archive in Property List Editor and see what it emitted. If the output contains an integer element, then it's the same as using `encodeInteger:forKey:`. If the output contains a data element, then it's the same as the solution I mentioned above. To be thorough, you should check the output from every architecture you support.

Comment: I don't *think* it's necessarily true that if the output contains an integer, it's the same as `encodeInteger:forKey:`. Plist integers are infinite-length strings, while `encodeInteger:forKey:` necessarily converts the argument something in the signed integer range.

Comment: @Chuck: Just checked. The NSNumber solution does handle numbers above `NSIntegerMax` correctly. One pitfall, though: In 32-bit mode, reading in a number greater than the 64-bit `NSIntegerMax` will bring it back as 0. @Johan Kool: You may want to use `encodeInt64:forKey:`/`decodeInt64ForKey:` instead.

Answer (score 26):

NSNumber has a lot of methods to store/retrieve different sized and signed types. It is the easiest solution to use and doesn't require any byte management like other answers suggest.

Here is the types according to Apple documentation on [NSNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithUnsignedInteger:(NSUInteger)value
- (NSUInteger)unsignedIntegerValue
```

Yes your code example is the best way to encode/decode the NSUInteger. I would recommend using constants for the key values, so you don't mistype them and introduce archiving bugs.

```
static NSString * const kCountKey = @"CountKey";

@interface MyObject : NSObject <NSCoding> {
    NSUInteger count;
}  

@end

@implementation MyObject

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:count] forKey:kCountKey];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        count = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:kCountKey] unsignedIntegerValue];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

That is the best way to do it. It does seem like needless work, but there's no other type available that can portably represent the entire range of values NSUInteger can hold.

Comment: This answer conflicts directly with what Matt Egan said in his answer/comment. I am thinking you are right though.

Answer (score -1):

You're going to want to use NSCoder's

```
encodeInt:ForKey:
```

and

```
decodeIntForKey:
```

methods. So, in your case you would need :

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeInt:count forKey:@"count"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        count = [decoder decodeIntForKey:@"count"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Hope that helps, also, there's plenty more encode "encode" methods, take a look at the documentation for NSCoder :D

Comment: I am aware of that method (and with the documentation). My question is wether this would be safe, given that `int` and `NSUInteger` are not the same thing.

Comment: @Peter That's what I thought. Can I encode a `NSUInteger` without wrapping it in a `NSNumber` or losing info?

Comment: Yes. Technically NSUInteger is simply an alias for an unsigned integer, that's what the "U" stands for. Again, yes, it is safe to use encodeInt: with a NSUInteger.

Comment: Johan Kool: I deleted my comment upon realizing that NSKeyedArchiver emits plist data and encodes integers as integer number elements in the plist. Of course, both emitting integer elements and the alternative bring other problems; see my answer.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. Well, I learned something today, didn't I? :D