# iPhone:How can I store UIImage using NSUserDefaults?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I cannot save image using nsuserdefaults and crash my app and I also used custom class UserInfo which used

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
   NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(categoryImage);
   [encoder encodeObject:categoryName forKey:@"name"];
   [encoder encodeObject:imageData forKey:@"image"];
}
```

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder and **userInfo.categoryImage is UIImage variable.**

**reason: '-[UIImage encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7676a70'**

```
userInfo = [[UserInfo alloc] init];

userInfo.categoryName = categoryName.text;
NSLog(@"Category Name:--->%@",userInfo.categoryName);

userInfo.categoryImage = image;

appDelegate.categoryData = [[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 userInfo.categoryName, @"name",userInfo.categoryImage,@"image", nil] mutableCopy];


[appDelegate.categories addObject:appDelegate.categoryData];
NSLog(@"Category Data:--->%@",appDelegate.categories);

[appDelegate.categories addObject:userInfo.categoryName];
[appDelegate.categories addObject:userInfo.categoryImage];

[self saveCustomObject:userInfo.categoryName];

[self saveCustomObject:userInfo.categoryImage];


-(void)saveCustomObject:(UserInfo *)obj
{
    appDelegate.userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *myEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:obj];


    [appDelegate.userDefaults setObject:myEncodedObject forKey:@"myEncodedObjectKey"];
}
```

So Please help me how can i store and retrieve uiimage using nsusedefaults???

Comment: The saveCustomObject hardly can work, because it stores every given object for the same key.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

UIImage does not implement NSCoding protocol, this is why you have the error.

Store:

```
NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSData* myEncodedImageData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:imageData];
[appDelegate.userDefaults setObject:myEncodedImageData forKey:@"myEncodedImageDataKey"];
}
```

Restore:

```
NSData* myEncodedImageData = [appDelegate.userDefaults objectForKey:@"myEncodedImageDataKey"];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:myEncodedImageData];
```

Comment: Make the `UserInfo` class implement 'NSCoding' protocol and archive the whole 'userInfo' object. Read this post of more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715038/how-to-store-a-nsuinteger-using-nscoding for example.

Comment: check my update code and see its crash at line [encoder encodeObject:categoryImage forKey:@"image"]; so please help me

Comment: You cannot encode the image, encode the data got from UIImagePNGRepresentation()

Comment: thanks a lot I successfully encode image please check my updated code but app is crash [<NSCFString 0x75135b0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.' so please help me

Comment: @NikunjR.Jadav: That's a different problem. Please ask a new question for that.

Comment: You should not do this line:  [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:imageData];  You can save the data after UIImagePNGRepresentation. Also you need to synchronize the userDefaults after setting the object.

Answer (score 33):

If I were you, I'll save the UIImage into a file (use the [myImage hash]; to generate a file name), and save the file name as NSString using NSUserDefault ;-)

Comment: For heavens sake, please accept this as the answer. Saving a UIImage on NSUserDefaults is really a dumb idea.

Answer (score 8):

Image Save on NSUserDefaults :

```
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) forKey:@"image"];
```

Image retrieve on NSUserDefaults:

```
NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"image"];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```