# store image array in nsuserdefault

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, nsuserdefaults

I have created an ios application where i need to store image array into nsuserdefaults. When restart the app again the storing image need to show in a scroll view. How can i store image array and get the array from nsuserdefault . Thank in advance.

Comment: Check this link [Importent for you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7620208/656600)

Comment: I suggest not to store image in NSUserdefault. I have tried before,it slows down the app.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
NSData *dataVal = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:val];
[defaults setObject:dataVal forKey:keyName];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
for(int val=0;val<[imageArray count];val++){
// imageArray is an Array which contains the Image Names
// See below converting the 
NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%d",[imageArray objectAtIndex]val]]);
    //add this `imgData` into dataArray(Which is An NSmutableArray don't forget to Allocate it)
    [dataArray addObject:imgData];
    //then Store this Array to NSuserDefaults
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dataArray forKey:@"key"];
}

// the Get the Stored Data Array from NSuserDefaults.
 NSMutableArray* storedDataArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults   standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"key"]];

 //`storedDataArray` array contains the ImageData(NSData)
 //Use it As you want
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(YOURIMAGE,1.0);
// Now store the NSData in the defaults for a  key
```

then load it like this

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[defaults objectForKey:@"Image"]];
```