# Save images in a n ios app

Tags: iphone

I am creating a greeting card app.I have some existing templates and i also can create new greeting cards by adding cliparts ,textstyles etc.I have saved the image as a uiimage object.I am stuck at the point to save these images for future use.Please help.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620165/iphonehow-can-i-store-uiimage-using-nsuserdefaults

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save a UIImage to file do the following

```
NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/img.jpg"];

//Save
NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0);
[imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

//Load
NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link.
[How to save picture to iPhone photo library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178915/how-to-save-picture-to-iphone-photo-library)

You can also save the image in iPhone file system by converting image to data and save data to file.

```
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage);
[data writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)useAuxiliaryFile]
```